# Pagination in Datagrid C# and SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, pagination, datagrid, limit

I really need some help. I have Datagrid with SQLite, I want to make pagination with all the data that loads in this datagrid from sqlite. I did all what I want to do, except "LastPage". I want to be loaded not all table, only the lasts rows that are <= 50. Maybe someone can help me with that? Here is my code:

```
int rowstart = 0;
int rowlimit = 50;

private void RefreshGridView()
{
dataGridView1.DataSource = DAL.Select("SELECT * FROM Sales LIMIT " + rowstart + "," + rowlimit + "");
}



private void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //HERE I NEED HELP - How to do ?
}
```

Many hours spend to find a answer ... but I didn't figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
var firstRowOfLastPage = (numberOfRows / rowsPerPage) * rowsPerPage;
var numRowsOnLastPage = numberOfRows - firstRowOfLastPage;
```

Comment: I dont think it will give correct number of the first row of last page. ( if we will take 5 rows per page )
62 - ( 62/5) * 5 = 62 - (12.4 * 5) = 0
In that case it will give 0 like a start row on last page, or I am wrong?

Comment: You forget that we are doing integer mathematics. fractions are simply thrown away: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HVAK9s (edited my answer for easier formula)

Comment: Yeah, you are right, i forghet that int take only integer. Thank you